# Trying to get the number of TD with CSS : background-position:1%;

Tags: jquery, selector

```
$("td[background-position='1%']").length
```

That would just return 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current syntax doesn't work because `background-position` would be either set in a rule of a CSS file so not available as an attribute, or the attribute would be named `style`, and the `background-position` would be somewhere in the value.

With that said, you can use `filter`:

```
var $tds = $('td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background-position') == '1%';
});
```

Comment: (And then `$tds.length`.)